# How to check whether MetaMask is installed?

Tags: metamask, javascript

How to check from client-side JavaScript whether MetaMask is installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [recommended way](https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/how-to/detect-wallet/metamask/) is to use `window.ethereum`:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    console.log('Ethereum support is available')
    if (window.ethereum.isMetaMask) {
      console.log('MetaMask is active')
    } else {
      console.log('MetaMask is not available')
    }
  } else {
    console.log('Ethereum support is not found')
  }
})
```

Comment: github link is dead

Comment: @alper fixed the link and updated code. Let me know if it works.

Comment: it works, thanks

Answer (score 8):

Not Metamask specifically, but the below checks if Web3 is being injected.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  // Check if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask).
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider.
    web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    // Handle the case where the user doesn't have web3. Probably 
    // show them a message telling them to install Metamask in 
    // order to use the app.
  }

});
```

Answer (score 4):

MetaMask's own onboarding library runs the test

```
window.ethereum && window.ethereum.isMetaMask
```

https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-onboarding/blob/v1.0.1/src/index.ts#L169

Then create a `Provider` using `new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)`

Answer (score 3):

```
if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
  console.log('MetaMask is installed!');
}
```

[Metamask documentation](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html#basic-considerations)

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer on the Metamask github page
https://metamask.github.io/metamask-docs/Advanced_Concepts/Provider_API#ethereum.on(eventname%2C-callback)

```
if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined'
|| (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined')) {

  // Web3 browser user detected. You can now use the provider.
  const provider = window['ethereum'] || window.web3.currentProvider
}
```

Then you call  `window.ethereum.enable()` to request user permission

Comment: broken link but good answer

Comment: I think this is the correct link:
https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html#basic-considerations

Comment: `window['ethereum']` is not a provider. You have to create a provider from this: `new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)`

Answer (score 1):

just 1 line:
`const isMetamask = ethereum.isMetaMask`

it will return true or error.

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw a different solution into the mix, here's a way to check on an interval in case you're up against loading issues. In this example, that interval is every second, it checks 15 times and then gives up.

```
((context) => {
  const checksBeforeStopping = 15
  let checksMade = 0

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (context?.ethereum?.isMetaMask) {
      console.log('MetaMask is installed')
      clearInterval(interval)
    } else console.log('Will check again in one second')
    
    if (++checksMade === checksBeforeStopping) {
      clearInterval(interval)
      console.log('Giving up on checking for MetaMask')
    }
  }, 1000)
})(window)
```